# How do you uninstall Modloader for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I was trying to install a mod for Minecraft, and it told me to install Modloader. I already had Forge installed, but I installed Modloader anyway, not knowing that the two mod loaders would clash. When I opened my Minecraft and logged in, it said Fatal Error, and it told me to uninstall one of the mod loaders.

I tried deleting Modloader, but that didn't do anything. I'm not really the tech-savvy type -- how can I completely remove Modloader?

Comment: Note that Forge includes ModLoader compatibility classes, so a mod that needs ML can be installed with Forge instead.

Answer (score 5):

If no-one else chimes in with a more elegant manner for cleanly removing modloader, what you can do is is delete the `bin` folder, which can be found in `%appdata%\.minecraft\` on Windows, or `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/` on OSX.

When you restart the client it will re-download the bin folder from the server.

Unfortunately this also means that you will need to re-install Forge and any other mods.

Comment: That's the only solution for uninstalling any mod that modifies the jar as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Minecraft launcher, click 'Options' and then select 'Force Update'. This will force the launcher to download a new version of the minecraft.jar. Then, once this is done, simply re-install Forge. And there you go!

You will not have to re-install any Forge mods because they are stored in a different folder.

Comment: In Minecraft 1.8, there's no Options button on the launcher.  In the game proper, there's an Options button but I do not see "Force Update".  Do you have updated information for the current version?

Answer (score 0):

What a do when a run in to problems like this i just force update my minecraft to do that, open minecraft go to options, force update, click done and login to minecraft hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:
Open Minecraft.
Go to "Options" above the "Log in" button.
Click "Force update".
Log in to Minecraft.
It will show all of the Updating... Stuff...
If you have an old computer like mine, Minecraft may freeze. If it does you must either close Minecraft or restart the computer.
Hope it helped!

Comment: Hi Ciara, and welcome to Arqade!  This is essentially the same information that's provided in another answer.  Please don't give a new answer unless you have something to add.

Comment: I did add something...